# How do you make it so a div gets sent to start if pushed outside container?

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to write some code that turns a string into a div box for each of the letters but the divs get pushed together if I have them go past there containers width and I would like it if instead they get put to the bottom and started another row Heres the code

```js
function display(string) {
    var x = []
    for(var m = 0; m < string.length;m++) {
        x.push(string[m])
    }
    x.forEach(function(e) {
        document.querySelector(".scene").innerHTML += 
            "<div class=" + e +"></div>"
 });
}
display("abab")
```

```css
.scene {
    display: flex;
    width: 150px;
}
.a {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: black;
}
.b {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: red;
}
div {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class='scene'></div>
```

Comment: pushed to start? next row? Past `.scene ` how?

Answer (score 1):

```js
function display(string) {
    var x = []
    for(var m = 0; m < string.length;m++) {
        x.push(string[m])
    }
    x.forEach(function(e) {
        document.querySelector(".scene").innerHTML += 
            "<div class=" + e +"></div>"
 });
}
display("abab")
```

```css
.scene {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 150px;
}
.a {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: black;
}
.b {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: red;
}
div {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class='scene'></div>
```

Comment: Thank you that is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure if I got your point properly but try to add this css in your .scene class: “flex-direction: column”

Answer (score 0):

You can set the outer `div` to have a `display` of `grid` and the inner `div`s to have a `display` of `table-row`:

```
.scene {
    display: grid;
    width: 150px;
}
.a {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: black;
}
.b {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: red;
}
.scene > div {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/chsL784p/